# Android. LocationManager. Изменение местоположения

Tags: android, java, gps

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо на фоне получать изменения координат, но не чаще чем через определенный промежуток времени.
Для этого использую Service. В нем:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            900000, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 900000, 0, locationListener);
```

Сюда же еще нужно добавить получение изменений координат полученных по сетям мобильного оператора.
Как сделать так, что бы координаты проверялись не чаще, например, чем через 20 минут?

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) написано

> Prior to Jellybean, the minTime parameter was only a hint, and some location provider implementations ignored it. From Jellybean and onwards it is mandatory for Android compatible devices to observe both the minTime and minDistance parameters.

А это значит, что в зависимости от устройства может работать заданное время, а может и не работать.
У вас также указано, что обновление должно происходить при преодолении дистанции в 0 метров.

Так что попробуйте на эмуляторе с JellyBean или выше со следующими параметрами.

```
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,

            30 * 1000, //30 секунд

            1000, //километр

            new MyLocationListener()

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Погляди [тут](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html). На хабре был хороший пост с исходниками.

Comment: @Garf1eld я делаю то же самое. Только смена местоположения уж очень часто срабатывает

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите хороший гугловский пример:   `android_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\maps\src\com\example\mapdemo\MyLocationDemoActivity.java`

В нем есть:

```
private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
        .setInterval(2000) // каждые 2 сек будет обновлять получение координат 
        .setFastestInterval(16)
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```